# How do I call derived functions from base variables in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, derived-class, abstraction

I am currently working with a a class, and three other classes that derive from that base class. The base class is supposed to be essentially abstract, so that I can call the virtual function of a base class, and have it do the expected function of the derived class. My end goal is to do something like this:

```cpp
class Car {
public:
    virtual void drive() = 0;  // Pure-virtual function
};

class Ford : public Car {
public:
    virtual void drive() { std::cout << "driving Ford\n"; }
};
```

This should work. In an empty file, this setup does work. My implementation must be wrong, but the c++ compiler doesn't give me any good hints on what the error is.

Currently, I am using a function to create the derived class, returning the base class to be used in main. I've tried all I could think of:

- Passing in a pointer that won't be destroyed after you exit
- Returning the derived class and storing into the base class
- Casting a base class/pointer into the derived class
- Setting a dereferenced base class pointer to a derived class

I just could not get it to work for the life of me. The virtual function just causes a seg fault whenever run from a base class variable.
Here is all of the code that I believe is relevant, in its current state, as I am testing.

Instruction.h:

```cpp
class Instruction {
    public:
        virtual void print(){};
        bool operator==(const int& rhs) const;
        void writeBack();
        void memory();
        virtual void execute(long registers[32], long dmem[32]){};
        unsigned int str2int(const char *str, int h);
        virtual ~Instruction(){};
};
```

ITypeInstruction.h:

```cpp
class IType: public Instruction {
    private:
        int op;
        string label;
        string rs;
        string rt;
        string immediate;
        map<string, string> registerMap;

    public:
        IType(int op, string label);
        IType(int op, string label, string rs, string rt, string immediate, map<string, string> registerMap);
        virtual void print();
        void execute(long registers[32], long dmem[32]);
};
```

ITypeInstruction.cpp:

```cpp
void IType::print()
{
    cout << "Instruction Type: I " << endl;
    cout << "Operation: " << label << endl;
    cout << "Rs: " << registerMap[rs] << " (R" << rs << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Rt: " << registerMap[rt] << " (R" << rt << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Immediate: 0x" << immediate << endl;
}
```

Decode.cpp:

```cpp
Instruction *decode(string binaryIn, map<string, string> registerSet, map<string, string> instructionSet, Instruction *instructionPointer)
{
        IType ins = IType(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);
        Instruction i = IType(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);
        ins.print();
        *instructionPointer = ins;
        (*instructionPointer).print();
        return instructionPointer;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
Instruction *instructionToExecute;
instructionToExecute = decode(instructionToDecode, registerSet, instructionSet, instructionToExecute);
instructionToExecute->print();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the code you show.

One is that you attempt to dereference the *uninitialized* `instructionPointer` variable.

Another is that `*instructionPointer = ins;` leads to [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Instead create the `IType` object *dynamically* and return a pointer to that object:

```
Instruction *decode(string binaryIn, map<string, string> registerSet, map<string, string> instructionSet)
{
    return new IType(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);
}
```

Note that the `instructionPointer` argument is no longer there.

Comment: Making a dynamic object was the solution I ended up going for. It's interesting that just by using the new keyword did all of my code just seemed to work. I had thought that just using the constructor was good enough. This solves my many weeks of research and bug testing!

Answer (score 3):

In `decode`, you're creating `IType` as a local variable, causing it to be destroyed when the function returns.

A more C++ style,

```
std::unique_ptr<Instruction>
decode(string binaryIn, map<string, string> registerSet, map<string, string> instructionSet)
{
  std::unique_ptr<Instruction> ins = std::make_unique<IType>(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);
  ins->print();
  return ins;
}

auto instructionToExecute = decode(...);
instructionToExecute->print();
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Instruction> decode(
    string binaryIn,
    map<string, string> registerSet,
    map<string, string> instructionSet,
    Instruction *instructionPointer)
{
  return std::make_unique<IType>(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);
}

int main() {
    // ...
    auto instructionToExecute = decode(instructionToDecode, registerSet,
        instructionSet, instructionToExecute);
    instructionToExecute->print();
}
```

What's going on: Variables defined in a function (and not marked `static`) don't live past the end of that function, except for a return value. You knew that a base class return type should be a pointer and not a base class type to avoid slicing, but then you need some way to provide a pointer to something that lives long enough to use. `std::make_unique` is the simplest way to do that.

Things that went wrong:

```
Instruction *decode(string binaryIn, map<string, string> registerSet, map<string, string> instructionSet, Instruction *instructionPointer)
{
        // OK, but the object "ins" lives only until the function returns.
        IType ins = IType(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);

        // Immediately slices to the base class, and isn't an IType any more.
        Instruction i = IType(opcode, label, rs, rt, imm, registerSet);

        // No problem.
        ins.print();

        // This uses the operator= of the base class Instruction.
        // It's probably not going to be able to handle assigning derived info
        // well, even if instructionPointer does in fact point at the same
        // derived type.       
        *instructionPointer = ins;

        (*instructionPointer).print();

        // This will be just the same pointer as the passed argument,
        // so doesn't really add any utility.
        return instructionPointer;
}

int main() {
    // ...

    // This pointer is an uninitialized value. Using it is as bad as
    // using the value of an uninitialized "int v;"...
    Instruction *instructionToExecute;

    // Uh oh. decode does *instructionToExecute = something;
    // But instructionToExecute is uninitialized and doesn't actually
    // point at any object to reassign! (Not even a base type object.)
    instructionToExecute = decode(instructionToDecode, registerSet,
        instructionSet, instructionToExecute);
```